# Qt unable to access object data from my function

Tags: c++, qt

My code compiles error free but the output to a little lcd panel I have should read 22. It reads the number 44 which is the initial value set in the constuctor. It is failing to update to a new value.
It appears `MainWindow::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply)`  is not being accessed and `ui->lcdNumber->display(22)` does not update the object as expected.
I can confirm that the connection does establish, I have wireshark running and I can see the software try and reach google, but nothing about that LCD I can get working because I cannot access the constructor object.
The purpose of the LCD is to reflect connection information, but right now I am just trying to reach the constructor.

//mainwindow.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QImageReader>
#include <QLCDNumber>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    ui->lcdNumber->display(44);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::connect()
{
    qDebug() << "connect";
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));

    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
}

void MainWindow::requestPage(){
    QUrl url("http://www.google.com");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

void MainWindow::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply){
    qDebug() << "finishedSlot";
    QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
    QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
    QString string(bytes); // string
    ui->lcdNumber->display(22);
//    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
//    {
//        QImageReader imageReader(reply);
//        QImage pic = imageReader.read();
//        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
//        QString string(bytes); // string
//        ui->lcdNumber->display(22);
        //qDebug()<<string;
//    }
//    else
//    {

//    }
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    requestPage();
}
```

//mainwindow.h

```
#ifndef MAINWINDOW_H
#define MAINWINDOW_H
#include <QMainWindow>
#include <QObject>
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>

namespace Ui {
class MainWindow;
}
class MainWindow : public QMainWindow
{
    Q_OBJECT
public:
    explicit MainWindow(QWidget *parent = 0);
    ~MainWindow();
private:
    Ui::MainWindow *ui;
public slots:
    void connect();
    void requestPage();
    void finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply);
    void on_pushButton_clicked();
private slots:
private:
    QNetworkAccessManager* nam;
};
#endif // MAINWINDOW_H
```

//main.cpp

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include <QApplication>

int main(int argc, char *argv[])
{
    QApplication a(argc, argv);

    MainWindow mConnect;
    mConnect.show();
    return a.exec();
}
```

Comment: Nothing seems to be calling `MainWindow::connect`. Perhaps this should be done somewhere, so `MainWindow::finishedSlot` will be called when `QNetworkAccessManager::finished`  signal is emitted.

Comment: @thuga I had a connect() in the on_pushButton_clicked function before, but at that time it gave me an infinate loop. I added connect() back in, no loop this time but same result as the post.

Comment: Call `MainWindow::connect` in the constructor, after initializing the `nam` object.

Comment: @thuga same result with the constructor as  {
    ui->setupUi(this);
    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    MainWindow::connect();
    ui->lcdNumber->display(44);
}

Comment: Not related to your question: you `new`ed a `QNetworkAccessManager` without parent. It's a memory leak.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Final working solution

```
#include "mainwindow.h"
#include "ui_mainwindow.h"
#include <QNetworkAccessManager>
#include <QUrl>
#include <QNetworkRequest>
#include <QNetworkReply>
#include <QImageReader>
#include <QLCDNumber>
#include <QDebug>

MainWindow::MainWindow(QWidget *parent) :
    QMainWindow(parent),
    ui(new Ui::MainWindow)
{
    ui->setupUi(this);
    nam = new QNetworkAccessManager();
    //connect2();
    //on_pushButton_clicked();
    QObject::connect(ui->pushButton, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(on_pushButton_clicked()));
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
    QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)), this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));
    ui->lcdNumber->display(66);
}
MainWindow::~MainWindow()
{
    delete ui;
}
void MainWindow::connect2()
{
    qDebug() << "connect";
    //QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(finished(QNetworkReply*)),
    //this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply*)));

    //QObject::connect(nam, SIGNAL(clicked()), this, SLOT(finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply)));
    //;
}

void MainWindow::requestPage(){
    QUrl url("http://www.google.com");
    QNetworkReply* reply = nam->get(QNetworkRequest(url));
}

void MainWindow::finishedSlot(QNetworkReply* reply){
    qDebug() << "finishedSlot";
    QVariant statusCodeV = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::HttpStatusCodeAttribute);
    QVariant redirectionTargetUrl = reply->attribute(QNetworkRequest::RedirectionTargetAttribute);
    QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
    QString string(bytes); // string
    ui->lcdNumber->display(11);
    qDebug()<<string;
//    if (reply->error() == QNetworkReply::NoError)
//    {
//        QImageReader imageReader(reply);
//        QImage pic = imageReader.read();
//        QByteArray bytes = reply->readAll();  // bytes
//        QString string(bytes); // string
//        ui->lcdNumber->display(22);
        //qDebug()<<string;
//    }
//    else
//    {

//    }
}
void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    requestPage();
    //connect();
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe it's me, but it seems that there's no connection between button `clicked` signal and `on_pushButton_clicked` slot.

Comment: I added connect() to the on_pushButton_clicked function. I am still getting the same response   void MainWindow::on_pushButton_clicked()
{
    requestPage();
    connect();
}

Comment: The connection is established by the auto generated code `setupUI` with `QMetaObject::connectSlotsByName`. This is not the problem.